# Vuejs3 with Vite have path issue electron

Tags: vue.js, electron, electron-builder

I have 2 problems, the first is that when I prescribe an array of links to images, these images are not processed by vite, and their path is not changed to absolute.

```
const crypto = [
  {
    img: "/img/qlogo.svg",
    title: "QDT",
    caption: "$0.003823",
    value: "37,663.31",
    semivalue: "≈$144.17",
    link: "/wallet/QDT"
  },
```

```
reftd(v-for="(item, ind) in crypto" :key="`${ind}pv`" :data="item")
```

As a consequence, after compilation through electron, the paths are /img/qlogo.svg instead of file:///.

The second problem is that when loading the application is not rendered immediately the main page, and rendered empty, and the main then can only go to the main page